# How to merge files in ClearCase with files from other directory?

Tags: clearcase

I have files in directory `/vobs/project/code_dir_staff/code` in some branch
and want to:

- merge this branch into another branch
- put this files in another directory `/vobs/project/sub_project/code` for example.

The destination '`code`' directory already exist and have some history.
I don't need source directory in destination branch.

How to do it simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would:

- First, do a classic merge.
- Then in the destination branch, move (through the ClearCase Explorer) those file to the existing code directory
- Finally remove (through the ClearCase Explorer) the directories you do not want to see.

That will work only for Base ClearCase, not for UCM (unless you are in a Vob component): you cannot move files (with their history) from one component to another.

Moving files from the ClearCase Explorer will preserve the history of files, will checkout the source parent directory and un-catalogued those files, and will checkout the destination directory to reference the same files.

Comment: I thought that there is some other way can be to do it. In any case thanks a lot for fast respond. I will do it in this way.

Comment: @user1173223: it is best to keep the two operations cleanly separate: first merge, then move.